# Credit default swap replication by corporative bonds

Tags: fixed-income, finance, finance-mathematics, financial-engineering

I want to get literature or information related with the topic of CDS replication for those counterparties that do not hold. But that have traded bonds (with different degree of liquidity). What could be the right way to transform the bond prices into CDS?

Comment: Are you looking for the default probability or just the CDS spread for those issuers?

Comment: For default probabilities

Comment: and for hedging purposes

Comment: Ok, so if you want to get the default probabilities for those companies that you cannot see their CDS spreads, you have two options (as far as I know). First one, use a proxy company.  Try to find a company in the CDS market that looks very similar to the company of your interest and use those spreads. The second method is related to the use of fixed income spread (over risk free). In practice, I see more financial institutions use the first approach but make sure the proxy  company is similar to the original.